# Exporting IEnumerable<x> or IEnumerable<y> in same method

Tags: c#

If I have two lists like this:

```
IEnumerable<Student> students;
IEnumerable<Teacher> teachers;
```

And I have written a method that exports the students list to an XML file and takes

```
IEnumerable<Student>
```

as input.

Is there a way that I could pass either list in and have the method export the data without worrying that it's a list of students or a list of teachers?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: do student and teacher inherit from the same base class or implement the same interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the items in the list would need to know how to export themselves.  You'd need to have each of the items implement an interface such as `IExportable` that has an `Export` method.  You can then create a method such as:

```
public static void ExportAll(IEnumerable<IExportable> sequence)
{
    //...
}
```

You could then pass a list of any type that knows how to export itself.

`IExportable` may end up being `ISerializable` for you, unless you intend to use some other means of exporting the items.

Comment: You could then pass a list of any type that knows how to export itself *provided that the type has a reference conversion to IExportable*. If it does not then you'd have to use a Select to do the boxing conversion. In this case I would be more inclined to `public static void ExportAll<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence) where T : IExportable` which then does not require a covariant conversion.

Comment: I have done as you suggested an implemented an IExportable interface and this works. But in my OutputFile method I still have foreach(Student s in sequence) when it could be Student s or Teacher s. How can I make the foreach loop generic?

Comment: Think I figured it out - implemented a base class like @Wieslaw suggested, and then made the base class and the two sub classes implement the interface like you suggested. Thanks for a really great lesson in OO :)

Answer (score 1):

Inherit from base abstract class, works great with serialization.

```
public abstract class Person
{
    // your code goes here
    // public string FirstName { get; set; }
    // public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    // your code goes here
}

public class Teacher : Person
{
    // your code goes here
}


public void Export(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
{
    // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - you just missed out on the accepted answer because I learned a bit more today from @Servy's post. But I did implement the base class too.

Answer (score 0):

Implement an IPerson interface on both Student and Teacher. Then change your XML export method to accept IEnumerable. The IPerson interface would have the methods you need to retrieve the data for XML export.